# Is Amazo weak against magic?

Tags: dc, cartoon, dc-animated-universe

In *"Wake the Dead"* Solomon Grundy is awakened from the dead, and is in part battled by Amazo. Amazo though has to leave as he is unable to effect the magically imbued Grundy.

Is this something that is canon in the DC comic universe? Or was it added in to the cartoon to de-power Amazo, and let the others shine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DC's canon differs between the comic books, the cartoons, and the movies.  Just look at the various takes on Batman.

Concerning the episode in question there is a brief synopsis here at the [Dc Animated Wiki](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Wake_the_Dead) which notes that this is not the same Solomon Grundy that they have met before but a creature filled with nothing but rage and chaos magic.  As Amazo blasts Grundy, he suddenly realizes there is a problem.  From the episode:

> Amazo: Something's wrong!  The creature is somehow feeding on my energies.  He adds my power to his own!  My presence here puts you all at risk.  I will retreat several light years distance until I can determine how to counter this effect.

This wasn't so much of a de-powering of Amazo as it was a way to get Amazo out of the picture.  This allowed Shayera Hol to make the ultimate choice to end the problem of Grundy.

Comment: I completely misremembered it! Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @Pureferret No problem.  I had to go back and rewatch it because i couldn't remember why Amazo left.

Answer (score 0):

Magick cannot be quantified by science. Thus, Amazo cannot "scan, copy, and paste" it to himself as he can abilities that are biological or technological in nature, or otherwise able to be analyzed by science.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was if Amazo is normally portrayed as weak against magic.  I'm not sure what you're responding to, but please don't post comments as answers.  You might want to take the [tour] to learn how to use the site effectively.

Answer (score -2):

Another thing is when Amazo battled the justice league he absored supermans powers and weaknesses giving himself a weakness to magic.

Comment: Actually in the later episode "The Return" he no longer had Superman's weaknesses as evident by the bunker Lex Luthor was hiding in being lined with Kryptonite, but the Kryptonite had no effect on Amazo.