# How does Grundy absorb Amazo's powers?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe

Stemming from [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11654/3804) question, it turns out I misremembered how Grundy is effected by Amazo in *"Wake the Dead"*. This is how it goes:

> Amazo: Something's wrong! The creature is somehow feeding on my energies. He adds my power to his own! My presence here puts you all at risk. I will retreat several light years distance until I can determine how to counter this effect.

How is this newly summoned Grundy 'feeding' on Amazo's powers? Firstly considering the numerous abilities Amazo has, which of these is being fed on? And secondly what possible function of Grundy is doing the feeding?

Is it some canon thing that  feeds Chaos magic? Or is it known that Chaos magic can feed on nearly anything? Or have the writers gone away from comic canon here, to tell a better story?

Comment: It wasn't comic canon but it was never explained in the episode either.  That was also the last appearance of both Grundy and Amazo in the series.

Comment: And thus never to be answered?

Comment: Unless you can contact the writers of the show I would doubt that there is an answer.  Sorry.

Comment: It's magic. If we understood how it worked, we'd call it science.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Grundy_%28comics%29#Television) page:

> He was resurrected by a dark spell cast by a group of young amateurs, which used chaos magic to inadvertently infuse him with the spirit of a powerful demon lord when the magic circle used to bind the demon in place was accidentally broken, allowing the demon to escape and possess the remains of Grundy, with his memory of his past incarnation severely addled and lacking the ability to speak. Mindless and uncontrollable, he goes on a destructive rampage, **his power augmented to levels far beyond his original self by the magic animating him**. After a lengthy battle with the Justice League, he regains a small fraction of his memory when he beholds Hawkgirl, whom he has accepted as a friend, and he submits to Shayera, who sorrowfully kills him to put him out of his misery.

The nature of the chaos magic allowed him to draw strength from Amazo's powers.

The Wikipedia article also says:

> While he has occasionally been destroyed, he has always returned to life sooner or later, though often with different personalities and powers.

Since Grundy had previously been killed and was reborn through the chaos magic, it fits that his powers would be changed from what they had previously been established. Those are some possible canon explainations.

**The out of canon explanation is likely that Amazo is too powerful to make for an interesting story, otherwise he could just instantly win. The writers had to come up with a reason Amazo wouldn't be able to participate in the fight. The solution was to make the chaos magic interact in some way with Amazo's powers that would require Amazo to leave.**

Answer (score 0):

It was just a plot thing.  AMAZO could've easily just pulled out Hawkgirl's mace himself and pummeled Grundy using superior speed and strength.